# matlab2tikz for binary matlab figures

Tags: pgfplots

How do you properly use `matlab2tikz` for binary MATLAB figures?

The figures are only black and white and when trying to generate the `.tex` file I get the error: `Input argument 'color' is not a scalar`.

Comment: I just stumbled about this question here and fixed it in matlab2tikz, cf. https://github.com/nschloe/matlab2tikz/commit/84b931e4085ff2e360d7e3dc9b6f7a5aad0fb1dd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matlab2tikz` expects numeric arrays being plotted. When you do plot a logical array, it throws this error. Convert your logical array to double before plotting, it shouldn't change the output, but let's `matlab2tikz` get the data.

```
data = rand(500,500);
databin = data > 0.5;

% this throws an error
% imagesc(databin);
% matlab2tikz('myplot.tikz');
databin = double(databin);
imagesc(databin);
% now it should work
matlab2tikz('myplot.tikz');
```

Comment: @Dana: The best thanks you can give is an upvote, and if you use the solution then later to accept the answer.